# Postgresql with "could not access status of transaction"

Tags: postgresql

I run with a select below:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE my_column LIKE '%my_word%'
```

But my system return:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe add a semicolon ?

Comment: well it says that commit log was erased :)

Comment: Joop: I don't think this problem.

Comment: Vao Tsun: Maybe it is a problem. Because, before I queried many times with this query, but this error appear yesterday.